# How to Depoly Vb.net Application containing Crystal Report and Access Database file

Tags: database, vb.net, deployment, crystal-reports, report

I am trying to build a setup file which will install my vb.net application with database and crystal report files to the client.

1.) I created my vb.net application in release mode.

2.) I created new setup project and added my vb.net application project in that solution.

3.) Also added the primary output in application folder

4.) [dun know how to add database so] created app_data folder inside the application folder and added the database file manually from add->file

5.) [dun know how to add crystal reports so] created reports folder inside the application folder and added the reports manually from add->file

6.) Build solution.

7.) Tried deploying in client machine.

8.) Application runs fine and works great. But crystal report files doesn't. When i try to open crystal report some long error messages comes in my way.

So I would like to know is the way i am doing to add the database file and crystal report files correct? how can i make crystal reports work in client machine?

PS: I am building my vb.net application in VS2008 and using Crystal Report 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are missing is the [Crystal Redistributable](http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp) package. It needs to be installed on the host.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give datasource location during runtime.

Because the problem is that while designing the crystal reports have to select database and regarding tables and fields right, but while running on clients machine it will not get the path which you have.